# How do you calculate the bouding rect for a string in Objective-C/Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Using Objective-C/Cocoa how do you calculate the width and height required to draw a string based on a particular font? In C#/.Net you can do it like this:

```
SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(someString, someFont);
```

Is there something like that available in Objective-C/Cocoa?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a specific example based on the answers given by danielpunkass and Peter Hosey:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello" attributes: attributes];
NSSize textSize = [text size];
```

For those new to Objective-C/Cocoa like myself an example really goes a long way. If you're coming from C++/Java/C# or whatever the Objective-C syntax can appear really foreign and since Apple doesn't embed much if any sample code in their Cocoa documentation, learning this stuff is kind of difficult.

Comment: +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?

Answer (score 7):

The following code is similar to what I use for a cross-platform text CALayer:

```
#if defined(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) || defined(TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
    UIFont *theFont = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:theFont];
#else
    NSFont *theFont = [NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
    CGSize textSize = NSSizeToCGSize([text sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:theFont forKey: NSFontAttributeName]]);
#endif
```

This gives you a CGSize for an NSString named text, with a font name of fontName and size of fontSize.

Answer (score 6):

One way is [`sizeWithAttributes:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:), as danielpunkass said. The other way is to create an NSAttributedString and ask that for its [`size`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/size). The only difference is that one way gives you an object with the text and attributes together (the attributed string), whereas the other keeps them separate.

Answer (score 4):

You use `NSString`'s [`sizeWithAttributes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a presenter e.g. `UILabel`/`NSLabel` (instead of asking the string to draw itself). Then you should ask this object the correct size.

See [Mike Weller's blog about labels](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html) for a detailed analysis.

Comment: There is no NSLabel. UILabel's Cocoa counterpart is NSTextField (with `bordered` and `editable` turned off).

Answer (score 0):

Ohh under iOS6 you can get the correct Size by this way:

```
CGSize textSize = [theString sizeWithFont:theFont
                             forWidth:160.0f
                        lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```